# How to get max record of earlier months when current month status is null in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to pull status, when current month is null, check previous month status without null and rank should be 1.
if previous month is also having null value in status for rank 1, then look for previous month from that.

For below scenario, I need to pull up march data because it is having status in rank 1

[image: ORACLE TABLE]

I have tried like below but not giving expected result

```
SELECT CLI.RANK,CLI.SERVICEMONTH,CLI.CLIENTID,CLI.STATUS,CLI.CREATETS         
FROM   (SELECT CLIENTID, SERVICEMONTH, CREATETS, STATUS ,
           Rank ()  OVER ( partition BY SERVICEMONTH  ORDER BY CREATETS DESC) AS RANK              
    FROM   CLIENTTABLE 
    WHERE  CLIENTID = 110011    
    ORDER  BY SERVICEMONTH DESC) CLI
WHERE CLI.RANK=1 AND CLI.STATUS IS NOT NULL
```

I need result as below

[image: result]

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: result added as requested

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impute the status for each client/service/rank combination, then you can use `lag(ignore nulls)`:

```
last_value(status ignore nulls) over (partition by client, service, rank order by servicemonth)
```

If you want the most recent status with a rank of 1 when there is no status, you can use:

```
coalesce(status,
         lag(case when rank = 1 then status end ignore nulls) over (partition by client, service order by servicemonth)
        )
```

EDIT:

If you just need the most recent row where `rank = 1` that has a status, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where rank = 1 and status is not null and
      clientid = 110011
order by servicemonth desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: it is not giving correct expected result as given in question .... result should come as 'TERMINATION'

Comment: @nirmal10 . . . What is it coming up with?  Can you set up a db<>fiddle?